# Multiple Base Url handling in one Ktor Client Instance

Tags: android, kotlin, interceptor, ktor, ktor-client

Hello i want to use Multiple Base urls one ktor client instance . i was able to acheive it in Retrofit 2 . but stuck in Ktor 2.1.0

IN retrofit here is my interceptor :

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("baseurl")
fun provideChangeBaseUrlInterceptor(controller: CLibController) = Interceptor { chain ->

    var host = controller.getENTBaseUrlOnline().toHttpUrl()

    var request: Request = chain.request()

    when {
        request.getAnnotation(HomeApi::class.java) == HomeApi() -> {
            host = controller.getENTBaseUrlOnline().toHttpUrl()
        }
        request.getAnnotation(OffersApi::class.java) == OffersApi() -> {
            host = controller.getOutletBaseUrlOnline().toHttpUrl()
        }
        request.getAnnotation(FavApi::class.java) == FavApi() -> {
            host = controller.getOutletBaseUrlOnline().toHttpUrl()
        }
        request.getAnnotation(ProfileApi::class.java) == ProfileApi() -> {
            host = controller.getAuthBaseUrlOnline().toHttpUrl()
        }
    }

    var newUrl: HttpUrl? = null
    try {
        newUrl = request.url.newBuilder().scheme(host.scheme).host(host.toUrl().toURI().host)
            .build()
    } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    assert(newUrl != null)
    request = request.newBuilder().url(newUrl!!).build()
    chain.proceed(request)
}
```

i have 7 base urls (Microservices backend) and each base url is accosicate with specific endpoints,SO i will acheive it with one instance of retrofit by categorize them with a custom annotations On my Api Class.
and get the Annotations in interceptor like the code above.Once i get the annotations of a request in interceptor i will changes it url to my desire url

Can any one help me achive this type of custom logic with ktor cleint (Single Client for multiple base urls )

Answer (score 1):

Okay i was finally able to make multiple base urls handled with one client instance . just like custom annotations ktor client gives us attributes to send custom data in any request .

here is the ktor client code :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideKtor(jwtToken: String, cLibController: CLibController): 
    HttpClient =

    HttpClient(Android) {

        defaultRequest {

            url {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                accept(ContentType.Application.Json)

                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                host = cLibController.getENTBaseUrlOnline()
            }

        }

        install(Logging) { level = LogLevel.ALL }

        install(ContentNegotiation) { gson { } }

        install(Auth) {
            bearer {
                loadTokens {
                    BearerTokens(jwtToken, jwtToken)
                }
            }
        }

    }.apply {
        plugin(HttpSend).intercept { request ->
            when (**request.attributes[MyAttributeKey]**) { // this is the key
                "homeApi" -> request.url.host = cLibController.getENTBaseUrlOnline()
                "profileApi" -> request.url.host = cLibController.getAuthBaseUrlOnline()
            }
            execute(request)
        }
    }
```

and setting my attribute key in each api class like :

```
client.post {
            attributes.put(MyAttributeKey, "profileApi")
            url {...}
}
```